# Regular Expressions to find a string included between two symbols while EXCLUDING the preceding / ending space

Tags: regex

I need to extract from a string a set of characters (TEXT1 / TEXT2 / TEXT3) which are included between two delimiters, without returning the delimiters themselves, nor the preceding or ending spaces.

My strings look like this:

1. **TEXT1 | characters**
2. **digits.digits - TEXT2 | characters**
3. **characters - digits digits-digits-digits - TEXT3 | characters**
4. **characters - digits digits/digits/digits - TEXT4 | characters**

Is it possible to write a **single** regex that would work to extract TEXT1 / TEXT2 / TEXT3 / TEXT4 for all strings above?

And what if my string looks like this?

1. **Lorem Ipsum dolor/sit** | LOT53 - Tc
2. 80.LT79 - **Lorem Ipsum Amet** | LOT25 - Ar
3. CT1: asda acar - 12 09-13-2022 - **Lorem Ipsum dolor/sit** | LOT54 - Ca
4. 52.85 Cat - 9/17/2021 - **Lorem, Ipsum & Dolor** | LOT12 - Ps

I need a **single** regex to extract what is bold.

Comment: can you provide some real use case for 4 of those ?

Comment: `^(?:[^|]*-)?\s*([^|]*?)\s*\|` [can help](https://regex101.com/r/QsaeM2/2).

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your examples/explanation, but perhaps a better approach would be to split by the well-defined delimiters instead of trying to "force" a single-regex solution? (Why must the answer be to use a single regex? It sounds like a potential XY problem to me...)

Comment: For example, maybe something like: `input.split(' - ').find { |x| x.include?(' | ') }[/\w+/]`, or maybe even just `input.split(' - ').last[/\w+/]`

Comment: Another idea `(?:^| - )([^-|]*) \|` https://regex101.com/r/CqfRuX/1 or if supported `(?<=^| - )[^-|]*(?= \|)` https://regex101.com/r/jfQTyY/1

Comment: I think (?<=^| - )[^-|]*(?= \|) is the solution!! Thank you so much @Thefourthbird!!! You are a life saver!!! Thanks so much everyone else, I have learned so much from you!

Comment: @Thefourthbird, is there a way I can modify (?<=^| - )[^-|]*(?= \|)

so that I can extract what I need if I sometimes have : instead of - ?

Examples:

1) 80.LT79 - Lorem Ipsum | LOT25 - Ar  ////
2) Car 1: Lorem Ipsum | LOT15 - Ar   ///
3) Lorem Ipsum | LOT14 - Dr ////

I need to extract Lorem Ipsum.

Thanks so much!

Comment: @AlexP Like this? https://regex101.com/r/qYIo2J/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Omg, thank you so much! You are a genius! I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `(?:-\h+)?(\w+)\h+\|`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cCYEwb/1)

---

Based on your edit, you can use the single regex:

```
(?:(?:-\h+)?([a-zA-Z]+\d+)\h+\|)|(\|\h+([a-zA-Z]+\d+))
```

to get tagged words of either form. You just need to figure out group 1 or group 2 programmatically after the match.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVhTM3/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\d-]*(\w+)\s?(?=\|)
```

`[^\d-]*` match all but digits and "-"

`(\w+)` match words

`\s?` match whitespace or not

`(?=\|)` lookahead "|"

you can also tinker it [here](https://regexr.com/6tm1h)